# Ember Cli Mirage: Active Model Adapter with JSONAPISerializer

Tags: ember.js, active-model-serializers, json-api, ember-cli-mirage, fastjsonapi

I am on halfway of implementing [JSON API](https://jsonapi.org/) structure (with underscore attributes).

---

**Actual state for development environment is**:

I use the [Active Model Adapter](https://github.com/ember-data/active-model-adapter) structure for requesting to the backend for resources and backend response me with [JSON API](https://jsonapi.org/) structure.

In Application Serializer I am using `JSONAPISerializer`. I override methods:

```
serializeBelongsTo
keyForRelationship
keyForAttribute
serialize
serializeAttribute
serializeHasMany
```

and for development, everything works for me (backend in Rails communicate with Ember very good).

---

**The problem** is with Ember CLI Mirage and conventions (not sure if there are simple solutions or I need to override again methods in this addon).

**Actual state with Ember Cli Mirage and test environment:**

I am using `import { JSONAPISerializer } from 'ember-cli-mirage';`
and then trying to manipulate proper request and then transform it for JSON API format.

It could work like this:

Ember Adapter (Active Model Adapter format - with underscore attributes) ---> Mirage Serializer should get request (find resources created before in tests with associations) and then response it with JSON API format ---> JSON API Serializer could catch it and fill Ember DS.

For now, I have a missing part to serialize it for all cases to JSON API standard (with underscored attributes)

Where should I do this transformation to minimize overriding JSONAPISerializer Mirage Serializer.

I noticed that there are some helpers, but I have a problem to wrap this knowledge together
(http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/advanced/route-handlers#helpers)

**UPDATE:**

Example of structure from Backend:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "6",
    "type": "first_resource",
    "attributes": {
      "id": 6,
      "my_attribute": "my_attribute"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "second_resources": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "16",
            "type": "second_resource"
          }
        ]
      },
      "third_resource_other_type": {
        "data": {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "third_resource"
        }
      },
      "fourth_resource": {
        "data": {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "fourth_resource"
        }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "fifth_resources": "/api/v1/first_resources/6/fifth_resources"
    }
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "fourth_resource",
      "attributes": {
        "id": 1,
        "my_attribute": "my_attribute"
      },
      "links": {
        "sixth_resource": "/api/v1/fourth_resources/1/sixth_resource"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "type": "second_resource",
      "attributes": {
        "id": 16,
        "my_attribute": "my_attribute"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "eighth_resources": {
          "data": []
        }
      },
      "links": {
        "seventh_resources": "/api/v1/second_resources/16/seventh_resources"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "type": "second_resource",
      "attributes": {
        "id": 17,
        "my_attribute": "my_attribute"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "eighth_resources": {
          "data": []
        }
      },
      "links": {
        "seventh_resources": "/api/v1/second_resources/17/seventh_resources"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "type": "second_resource",
      "attributes": {
        "id": 15,
        "my_attribute": "my_attribute"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "eighth_resources": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "26",
              "type": "eighth_resource"
            },
            {
              "id": "24",
              "type": "eighth_resource"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "links": {
        "seventh_resources": "/api/v1/second_resources/15/seventh_resources"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "type": "eighth_resource",
      "attributes": {
        "id": 26,
        "my_attribute": "my_attribute"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE2**

structure from mirage response:

```
data: {
  attributes: {
    my_attribute: 'my_attribute',
    second_resource_ids: [36, 37],
    fifth_resource_ids: []
  },
  id: 11,
  relationships: {
    third_resource_other_type: {data: null}
    fourth_resource: {data: null}
    second_resources: {data: []}
  },
  type: "first_resources"
}
```

resources in tests:

```
server.create('second-resource', {
  id: 36,
  first_resource_id: '11',
  my_attribute: "my_attribute"
});

server.create('eighth-resource', { 
  id: 140,
  second_resource_id: 37
});

server.create('eighth-resource', {
  id: 141,
  second_resource_id: 37
});

server.create('second-resource', {
  id: 37,
  first_resource_id: '11',
  eighth_resource_ids: [140, 141]
});

server.create('first-resource', {
  id: 11,
  second_resource_ids: [36, 37]
});
```

**first_resource model in mirage:**

```
export default Model.extend({
  third_resource_other_type: belongsTo(),
  fourth_resource: belongsTo(),
  fifth_resources: hasMany(),
  second_resources: hasMany()
});
```

Comment: Could you post an update with a simple example of a JSON payload that's coming from your Rails server, as well as what the corresponding Mirage response looks like for the same endpoint?

Comment: @SamSelikoff updated example of the response from my backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to focus a single relationship, since there's a lot going on in the question you've posted. We'll look at `second-resource`.

It looks like Mirage is sending back `second_resource_ids` under the `attributes` key of the `first_resource` primary data in the JSON:API payload. That tells me Mirage thinks `second_resource_ids` is an *attribute* of `first_resource`, when in fact it's a relationship.

Assuming your Models & Relationships are setup correctly, you need to tweak the way you're creating data in Mirage.

If you take a look at the [Associations section of the Defining Routes guide](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/writing-your-server/defining-routes), you'll see this message:

> Mirage's database uses camelCase for all model attributes, including foreign keys (e.g. authorId in the example above)

Right now, you're doing this:

```
server.create('second-resource', {
  id: 36,
  first_resource_id: '11',
  my_attribute: "my_attribute"
});

server.create('first-resource', {
  id: 11,
  second_resource_ids: [36, 37]
});
```

But from Mirage's perspective, you need to use `camelCase` IDs, or just pass in the relationships, to set these up correctly. Something like this:

```
let firstResource = server.create('first-resource', {
  id: 11
});

server.create('second-resource', {
  id: 36,
  firstResource,
  myAttribute: "my_attribute"
});
```

You could also pass in the foreign key on creation if you wanted - just be sure to use camelCase:

```
server.create('second-resource', {
  id: 36,
  firstResourceId: '11',
  myAttribute: "my_attribute"
});
```

Just remember that the formatting decisions for things like attributes and foreign keys (things like `some-attribute` vs. `some_attribute` or `relationship-id` vs. `relationship_id`) are made at the *serializer* layer. When dealing with Mirage's ORM and database, you want to stick to `camelCase`, regardless of the format your Serializer emits.

---

For more information, have a look at these sections from the docs:

- ["Associations and serializers" section of the Quickstart](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/quickstart#associations-and-serializers)
- [Defining relationships](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/advanced/defining-relationships)
- ["Working with relationships" section of the Factories guide](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/advanced/factories#working-with-relationships)

Comment: Thank you for these advices, I was confued on some stuff, because there were 

dasherized: "server.create('second-resource', {"
camelCased: "firstResourceId: '11',"
underscored: "'second_resources': {"

I also noticed that I had some bad configured things.
After I improved these connections plus fixed associations on serializers

I added too:
  alwaysIncludeLinkageData: true,

  keyForRelationship(key) {
    return underscore(key);
  },

  keyForAttribute(attr) {
    return underscore(attr);
  },

normalizeIds: 'always',
normalize(payload) {
(...)
}

Comment: Now the documentation is much better than I started with it. I appreciate it.
After what I add there I don't see "links: {" on my response, not sure if it's correct bahavior on mirage or I need set something else too.

Comment: Check out the links section of the [Serializer](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/api/modules/ember-cli-mirage/serializer~Serializer#links) documentation, or if you're not using JSONAPISerializer you can add them after calling "super" in the serialize method (check the `serialize` method docs).

Comment: Thank you for the answers and to show me these links which stuck to the point.

After these suggestions, I refactored around 100 files. One of the most confused things were when mirage factory has for example `my_type` (with underscore) - this attribute works with server.create('resource'). When I did server.create('resource', {my_type: 'something'}) it worked. When I did server.create('resource', {myType: 'something')) it didn't work. When I changed factory to `myType`, then `server.create('resource', {myType: 'something'))` worked. I had a mix of it and that caused a headache. Thanks.